# have_posts is empty on category.php

Tags: categories, templates

All the applicable code is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nicjohnson/5953612).

I have a really simple `category.php` template. I have 3 posts, each belonging to the same parent category, and 2 belonging to one child category and the third belonging to the other child category.

When I use `wp_list_categories` to generate the category links, it works fine. But when I click the link to look at any of the categories, I get the `else` from the `have_posts` `if` statement.

Comment: Please post the problem code in your question as a reference, you can link to your debug output though.

Comment: are your posts of the type `post` and not a custom post type? what happens if you disable plugins and use a default theme?

Comment: @Milo, good call on the custom post type.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it turns out that a simple function on the `pre_get_posts` filter [does the trick](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/make-archives-php-include-custom-post-types/). The issue was that custom post types aren't included in the default query.

Comment: Could you share the function please? Thanks